# How to toggle text on h3 headers of accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, toggle, accordion

My h3 headers serve as the trigger for a jquery-driven accordion.   I'd like to be able to append the words " (click me)," toggling that phrase on and off when the header is clicked.  (Remove the words when clicked, append them when "off").  The code, as written, works great... except that it places the text of the first h3 found into all headers. ("Header One" and "Header Two" becomes "Header One (click me)" and "Header One (click me)."  I'm guessing I need some version of "foreach" - but it's got me stumped.

I was inspired by the info found here [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433331/how-can-i-toggle-text-in-the-header-of-the-jquery-accordion) - but it's different enough that I found myself stalled out in my adaptation.

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".ui-accordion-header").not('.ui-state-active').append(' (click me)');

$(".ui-accordion-header").click(function () {

var originaltext = $(this).text();             
var replacetext = " (click me)";      
var newtext = originaltext.replace(replacetext,'');

$(".ui-accordion-header").text(newtext);

$(".ui-accordion-header").append(' (click me)');

$(".ui-accordion-header.ui-state-active:contains('lick')").text(newtext);
});

});

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly I think your issue is that you are putting the text of the header that was clicked on into all of the headers.  Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jr0Lad79/):

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".ui-accordion-header").not('.ui-state-active').append(' (click me)');

        $(".ui-accordion-header").click(function () {

            $(".ui-accordion-header").each(function(){

                var originaltext = $(this).text();             
                var replacetext = " (click me)";      
                var newtext = originaltext.replace(replacetext,'');
                $(this).text(newtext);
            });

            $(".ui-accordion-header").not('.ui-state-active').append(' (click me)');
        });    
    });    
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!  I've compared yours to mine in an effort to better understand this and the comparison sheds much light.  Thanks again!